# Docusign Connect retry frequency when require acknowledgement enabled

Tags: docusignapi

What is the retry frequency for an account that has Connect enabled and the "Require Acknowledgement" setting turned on, assuming that the endpoint on our side does not reply with a successful acknowledgement each time it is hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/connect.htm#Checking2)

If the **Require Acknowledgement** option is selected and a publication message fails to be 
acknowledged, the message goes back into the queue and the system will retry delivery after a 
successful acknowledgement is received. If the delivery fails a second time, the message is not returned to the queue for sending until Connect receives a successful acknowledgement and it has been at least 24 hours since the previous retry. There is a maximum of ten retries.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too, but there are all kinds of problems with the wording of that paragraph. Assuming that a "successful acknowledgement" is a 200 response to the callback, I would think that the last part of the first sentence should be "the system will retry delivery **until** [not 'after'] a successful acknowledgement is received". Although the second sentence makes it sound like a successful acknowledgement is something we have to initiate, which defeats the purpose entirely. My understanding is that Docusign sill continue retrying at some interval until we return a 200.

Comment: If Connect sends a message (let's call it "Message_1") to your listener and does not receive a 200 response, it places that message in the failure/retry queue.  It will not retry that message (Message_1) until **after** a 200 response is received for **another** (different) message.

Comment: So, if your listener goes down for 10 minutes and a bunch of messages are placed in the failure/retry queue during that downtime, then your listener comes back up, another envelope event occurs, Connect sends the message for that event and receives a 200 response -- Connect will then reattempt delivery of messages in the failure/retry queue at that time (according to retry logic that's specified in the Connect guide).  There is no "retry interval" -- the retry logic relies entirely on whether or not your listener is receiving/acknowledging Connect messages at any given point in time.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks so much, Kim, that was very helpful. Also, that's a really clever way for Docusign to implement the retry without having to setup a fancy system of retries at various intervals.

Comment: @KimBrandl what is the behaviour when the option is not selected? Do they try to send the notification to salesforce only once? What happens if the first notification fails?