# Docusign webhook listener - is there a retry?

Tags: docusignapi

I had a question on using a listener with the webhook architecture. If my site or page that will be doing the listening is done for any reason, what happens to the response that got posted? Does Docusign try to repost that info or is it lost for good? I'm assuming that Docusign posts and if nothing is there listening, then the response is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options

1. During [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) you can specify the **requireAcknowledgment** property in your [eventNotification](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definition-eventNotification)

> **requireAcknowledgment** : When set to true, the DocuSign Connect service checks that the message was received and retries on failures.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935618/docusign-connect-retry-frequency-when-require-acknowledgement-enabled) for the retry rules

---

2. You can use the [ConnectEvents:retryForEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/retryForEnvelope/) api to republish Connect information for the specified envelope.

   PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/connect/envelopes/{envelopeId}/retry_queue

There are additional connect related Apis that you might be interested.

Documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/)

Comment: I did not know about the requireAcknowledgement property. Thank you.