# How to get docusign webhook to retry on failure?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm able to correctly set up and monitor any changes to docusign envelopes.

However, I'm trying to get this edge case working: if my listener is not active, I want docusign to retry.

I've tried adding "requireAcknowledgment" to true when creating my envelope, however, that does not seem to change anything. I can see the failures on my admin panel's connect tab. But they only retry if I manually trigger them.

```rb
event_notification = DocuSign_eSign::EventNotification.new({
          :url => webhook_url,
          :includeDocuments => false,
          :envelopeEvents => [
            DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeEvent.new({:envelopeEventStatusCode => "sent"}),
            DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeEvent.new({:envelopeEventStatusCode => "delivered"}),
            DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeEvent.new({:envelopeEventStatusCode => "completed"}),
            DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeEvent.new({:envelopeEventStatusCode => "declined"}),
            DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeEvent.new({:envelopeEventStatusCode => "voided"}),
          ],
          :loggingEnabled => true,
          :requireAcknowledgment => true #retry on failure
        })
        # create the envelope definition with the template_id
        envelope_definition = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new({
          :status => 'sent',
          :eventNotification => event_notification,
          :templateId => @template_id
        })
```

Some related threads that I've looked into: [Docusign webhook listener - is there a retry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951220/docusign-webhook-listener-is-there-a-retry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign Connect webhook system has two queuing / retry models. The standard one is the "aggregate" model. The new one is "send individual messages" (SIM) model.

You probably have the aggregate queuing model. Its retry procedure is:

The first retry for envelope "1" will not happen until (24 hours have passed and an additional message for the configuration for an envelope 2 succeeded.)

But, if an envelope 1 message fails, and then there is a different message (different event) also for envelope 1, the second message will be tried whenever its event occurs (even if less than 24 hours). If it succeeds, then the first message will never be re-sent (since it was superseded by message 2).

(Drew is partly describing the SIM retry model.)

### To switch to the SIM model

Use the eSignatures Administration tool. See the **Updates** section in the **Account** part of the navigation menu.

Answer (score 1):

Connect will retry automatically once a successful publish to the same endpoint has occurred. If the first retry fails, a second will not be attempted until 24 hours have passed.

Comment: If I understand correctly:
When a webhook update to `Envelope1` fails, and then a webhook update to `Envelope2` succeeds, 
Docusign will automatically retry to update `Envelope1`.

This is not happening currently for me. I am unable to trigger a retry.