# Webhook retries and different accounts

Tags: docusignapi

We will be just an integrator providing DocuSign services to our clients that have DocuSign accounts via OAuth authentication in our application. Some of our clients will have significantly higher volume than others.

If we set the RequireAcknowledgement flag on the envelope's event notification and the initial post to the webhook url fails (due to server down, etc.) for account 1 (low volume client) and then a subsequent post succeeds (server back up) for account 2 (high volume client) will the post for account 1 be retried or would they have to wait for the indeterminate time (could be hours or days) between requests for their account?

In other words, is the retry tied to the individual account having a successful post or to our integrator key or notification url having a successful post?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And please check (accept) the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 2):

The retry logic is based on the Connect *subscription* (also known as the Connect configuration.)

If you're creating a Connect subscription at the account level then each account has its own subscription. (Even though the same Integration Key is being used.)

If you're using the per-envelope `eventNotification` technique for creating per-envelope subscriptions, each envelope is a different subscription.

[Details on the retry logic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18938573/64904)

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, if we're using per envelope eventNotification, as soon as any envelope that uses the same subscription URL succeeds, any previous per envelope eventNotification failures for that subscription URL will be retried regardless of the account of the envelope. Is that correct?

Comment: No, the per-envelope subscriptions are independent of each other. If you're worried about restarting the various envelope subscriptions, you can poll the Failure queues (there's one per account) and use the API to restart failed notifications. Also, build your listener to have high reliability. Eg: pool of listener servers behind a load balancer, and only use the listener to put the notification into a reliable queue system.

Comment: So then, since each envelope subscription is independent, even with RequireAcknowledgement set to true it would never get retried as there would never be a subsequent successful attempt on that subscription?

In other words, with Connect and a single account it would be retried after there was a successful post. It seems that would never be the case here. Correct? The documentation is not precise in this regard for eventNotification settings at the envelope level. Either that or I am not seeing where it is addressed.